# Images in products are not fully displaying when using WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on WordPress WooCommerce, the thumbnail image is not fully showing.
site URL:tulipmark.com/product-category/womens/ethenic-wear/saree you can see the problem in the link provided above

Comment: what do you mean not coming full?

Comment: is your site available? hard to diagnose problem from this much information

Comment: I took a look at your site, you should regenerate your thumbnails but remove the cropping option for the thumbnails and other image sizes.  It's under Settings/Products/Dsiplay.  Then the heads won't be chopped off in your product images.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz Thanks for your precious reply but as you said i look in simple settings there was no product option also i checked in Woo-commerce setting there product option was there but Display option was not their can plz tell me in which setting i have to go their.
Thanks Anurag

Comment: Trust me the settings are there, watch this video and at 33sec mark it will show you where the settings are. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVLb3eG0JdI  Untick the hard crop checkbox and regenerate your thumbnails with a plugin like this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/